# Core Data - Select distinct

Tags: ios, core-data, nsmanagedobject

I know there have been several discussions about this but none of them resolved my simple problem.

I have an Entity called Character and inside there are 4 columns:
character_id, episode_id, title, desc

there can be several same character_ids values but with different episode_id.

When I perform fetch\select I do it for whole table and wishes to get it distinctly by character_id. so this is what I do:

```
NSFetchRequest *fetchRequest = [[NSFetchRequest alloc] init];
NSEntityDescription *entity = [NSEntityDescription entityForName:entityName    inManagedObjectContext:moc];
[fetchRequest setEntity:entity];

// Add a sort descriptor. Mandatory.
if(sortDescriptors != nil) {
    [fetchRequest setSortDescriptors:sortDescriptors];
}

fetchRequest.predicate = predicate;

// Required! Unless you set the resultType to NSDictionaryResultType, distinct can't work.
// All objects in the backing store are implicitly distinct, but two dictionaries can be duplicates.
// Since you only want distinct names, only ask for the 'name' property.
fetchRequest.resultType = NSDictionaryResultType;
fetchRequest.propertiesToFetch = [NSArray arrayWithObject:[[entity propertiesByName] objectForKey:@"title"]];
fetchRequest.returnsDistinctResults = YES;


NSArray *fetchResults = [moc executeFetchRequest:fetchRequest error:&error];
```

The 'fetchResults' array contains 3 out of 10 rows which is the right result!

The problem: None of the object within the array is accessible.

If I try the following:

```
NSDictionary item1 = [fetchResults objectAtIndex:0];
NSString *title = [item1 objectForKey:@title"];
```

I get an exception!

What am I doing wrong?? how can I translate back the dictionary into NSManagedObjects??

Thank you!

Comment: On a side note, I see many typos (or unintentional mistakes) in your code. For example : `NSDictionary item1 = [fetchResults objectAtIndex:0]; NSString *title = [item objectForKey:@title"];` should have the `title` string being obtained from `item1` instead of `item` and `NSDictionary item1 = ...` is missing a `*` etc.

Comment: Yeah, it's because I typed this code instead of copy\paste from my real code :-)

Comment: Still did you double check for names? Also try to log the class of the objects that result array holds. May be that can give you some idea.

Comment: Please copy/paste (the relevant parts of) your *real running* code, together with the actual and expected output. Everything else is just wasting (yours and our) time. For example your posted code sets propertiesToFetch=title, and later retrieves `[item objectForKey:@title"]`, which definitely should just work. The character_id, for which you want the distinct values, does nowhere occur in your code.

Comment: You can't, there is no 1:1 mapping between the dictionary contents and the managed objects - that's the whole point of what you did...

Comment: An example data set together with the desired result would also be very helpful.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, when using Core Data you should not use foreign keys. Rather, it is preferable to use Core Data's relationships and let the framework deal with the ids in an opaque manner. Maybe you are synching with a web service and need to keep track of the ids but your program logic actually should not depend on it.

Second, if you need an object, it is really better to use the `NSManagedObjectResultType` rather than the `NSDictionaryResultType`. You can still obtain distinct results. If you are not experiencing performance issues, this is the preferred pattern. The code is also much more readable.

Your data structure would be this, with a many-to-many relationship:

`Character <<--->> Episode`

All characters of an episode or all episodes with a certain character is simple. These will be "distinct" results dictated by the logic of the data model:

```
NSArray *allCharactersInEpisode = episode.characters;
NSArray *allEpisodesWithCharacter = character.episodes;
```

To select all characters of all episodes you just select all characters. Much simpler than a "distinct" query.

Comment: Ok, I understand that I need to work with relations.
I actually have 2 entities in model:
1. Character
2. Episode

so if I understand you correctly, I need to make relationship between Episode and Character (Many-to-Many) and then when I will run my query on Character table it will return distinct rows only??

Comment: Of course! You got it. See the power of the object graph as opposed to a crude database?